# Is there any way to check/verify if a ppa repository is safe, or has been flagged by someone for some reason somewhere on the internet?

Tags: ppa, malware

You ve got a lot of ppa repos out there, and everyone seems to link add and download from these without checking (i assume). Is there a way to verify safety of a ppa somewhere on the internet ?